# Comparison of two Positive/negitive data sets of different sizes

Tags: statistical-significance, biostatistics

I'm comparing to data sets for recovery of fungi using two type of media. Set 1 has about 12x or 24x the number of total date points as set 2. So, each parameter for set two has ~48 data points per sample location vs 12 or 24 times that for set 1. The question here is if both types of media are equivalent in the recovery of fungi. The issue is the positive occurrence is very low (far <5%) for positive recoveries, so a recovery of 1 for both data sets looks like Set 2 has a far greater recovery rate in simple [# of samples/ number of positive recoveries percentage], but that doesn't seem statistically relevant.

Is there some non arbitrary way to weight each set so a statistical comparison isn't skewed by the total sample size. Or some other way of looking at the data?

Comment: what about looking at % recovery per data point?